# How to shorten path when import them in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

I created a folder named 'models' in pyramid project directory, and put all my models there in separate files, like:

```
models
  |------ User.py
            |------- class User
  |------ Group.py
            |------- class Group
```

In some scripts like initializedb.py, I have to write something like

```
from ..models.User import User
from ..models.Group import Group
```

which was pretty ugly. How to shorten 'em to

```
from ..models import User
from ..models import Group
```

without add something redundancy like

```
from .User import User
from .Group import Group
```

in models/**init**.py?

Comment: Why are you putting each class in a separate file?  There is usually no reason to do this in Python.

Comment: Just because you don't *have* to have one class per module in Python doesn't mean it's not a helpful way of managing large bodies of code.

Comment: Yep, I did this because it makes my project more clear and easy to understand. I hate a large file which contains everything in it....:-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do it is via `models/__init__.py`:

```
from User import User
from Group import Group
```

This turns `models` into a package, and will allow you to use `from ..models import User`.

One word of advice: the standard practice is to have all lower-cased module names and reserve capitalisation for classes. This allows you to have both `user` the module and `User` the class in the same namespace at the same time, which can be handy if the module contains convenience functions for working with the class.

Comment: It seems that I have to put all models in a single file to make my code clean... :-( Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You *could* create a generic `__init__.py` that traverses all Python files in a folder tree and does an `import *` for each, and then specify in each file which items you want to allow to export by defining `__all__`. However, I find the manual way is a lot more flexible and easier to understand in the long run.

Comment: I'm very interested in the traverses way... Could you share the code with me?

Comment: Added as a separate answer to make comparison easier.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a rough & dirty example of how you might possibly automate it.  Create an `__init__.py` with the following:

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import pkgutil

def auto_importer():
    here = os.path.split(__file__)[0]
    for _, package, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules( [here] ):
        package_name = '%s.%s' % (here, package)
        if package_name not in sys.modules:
            __import__( package_name )
            module = sys.modules[package_name]
            public_members = (m for m in getattr(module, '__all__', dir(module)) if not m.startswith('__'))
            for member in public_members:
                globals()[member] = getattr(module, member)

auto_importer()

# clean up namespace to avoid these leaking out
del os, sys, glob, pkgutil
del auto_importer
```

This will import everything from each contained module that isn't prefixed with `__` (so we don't pull in all the special attributes from each module, like `__file__`). If you only wanted to import, say, the `Group` class from your `group` module, you'd add a line to `group.py` as follows:

```
__all__ = [ 'Group' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's not any way to do what you're asking, without importing within models/__init__.py. Or, including all of your models in a single .py file, instead of a separate .py file for each.

Sorry.

Comment: If I have to modify the models/__init__.py, how? Thanks